# Unable to query sql table with mamp

Tags: php, mysqli, mamp

I am having trouble with queries, I am using mamp and database connects with sql with not error but I can't query table values, I get nothing with my query code. please help...

```
<?php
//function.php 
function dbConnect($server,$username,$password,$database){
    $connect = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$database);
    if($eror=$connect->connect_error){
      die("dbfailure [".$eror."]");
    }//echo "dbConnected";
}
```

?>

```
<?php include('./function.php'); dbConnect('localhost','dbtBL','dbtBL','dbtBl');?>
```

";
          }

        ?>

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: @webpic it was wrong formatted, i suggested an edit.

Comment: before while loop check `mysqli_num_rows($q)>0`

Comment: @ Tobias F. I went through your post but couldn't understand it, I am just a beginner

Comment: @ web pic, I tried your method and still don't get anything.